# Replacing word in text file- python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7, replace

I have 2 files as shown below

Branch Data:

```
open bus from 2311 to 3223 ck 1
open bus from 4321 to 3783 ck 1
.
.
.
```

I have around 100 branches like this

infile:

```
contingency 'b2_452'
QQQQQQQQ
open bus from 4321 to 3784 ck 1
end
.
.
.
```

I have around 200 contingencies like this

I am trying to get the output as shown below

excepted output files:

file1

```
contingency 'b2_452'
open bus from 2311 to 3223 ck 1
open bus from 4321 to 3784 ck 1
end
```

file2

```
contingency 'b2_452'
open bus from 4321 to 3783 ck 1
open bus from 4321 to 3784 ck 1
end
```

Here is my code

```
infile = open('Contingency.txt').read()
Brachdata = open('BranchData.txt', 'r')
i = 0
for branchline in Brachdata:
    replace1 = branchline
    i = i + 1
    outputfile = open('file' + str(i) +'.txt', 'w')
    for line in infile:
        outputfile.write(line.replace('QQQQQQQQ', replace1))
outputfile.close()
```

I am new to python programming and not sure where I am going wrong. This code is creating two copies of my infile... not replacing QQQQQQQQ with the line.

Comment: As an aside: you don't have to stick with "line" in your `for` loops, you can just name it whatever you want. In the first for-loop, for example, you can say `for branchline in Brachdata:`.

Comment: @DaanWilmer Thank you.. post a question here is a good learning experience :)

Comment: I changed `infile = open('IM Sub.txt').read()` to `infile = open('IM Sub.txt', 'r')` then it is adding the branch in the first file but leaving the other files blank with no data in it.

Comment: Also, try & use the `with` statement. The file closing is handled by the `with` statement itself. It is more pythonic. e.g. `with open('file' + str(i) +'.txt', 'w') as outputfile: ...`

Comment: it is just creating empty files..

Comment: When I edited my code to `with open( 'IM Sub' + str(i) +'.con', 'r+' ) as outputfile:` It is showing me an error **IOError: [Errno 0] Error** at `outputfile.write(line.replace('QQQQQQQQ', replace1))`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem is.. here is the updated code

```
f2 = open('Contingency.txt', 'r')
f1 = open('Contingency new.txt', 'w')

for line in f2:
    if 'QQQQQQQQ' in line:
        f1.write("    @")
    else:
        f1.write(line)
f1.close()

Brachdata = open('BranchData.txt', 'r')
infile = open('Contingency new.txt').read()

i = 0
for branchline in Brachdata:
    replace1 = branchline
    i = i + 1
    outputFile = open('Contingency' + str(i) +'.txt', 'w')
    for line in infile:
        if '@' in line:
            outputFile.write(replace1)
        else:
            outputFile.write(line)
Brachdata.close()
```

Comment: `.read()` is basically reading one alphabet at a time. So i replaced it with a special character and it works perfect.